# How to reduce one month from current date and stored in date variable using java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time

How to reduce one month from current date and want to sore in `java.util.Date` variable
im using this code but it's shows error in 2nd line

```
 java.util.Date da = new Date();
 da.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1); //error
```

How to store this date in `java.util.Date` variable?

Comment: you can use getMonth() and setMonth() method of java.util.Date to do this task. but they are deprecated

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use Calendar:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
Date result = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 27):

Starting from Java 8, the suggested way is to use the [Date-Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) rather than `Calendar`.

If you want a `Date` object to be returned:

```
Date date = Date.from(ZonedDateTime.now().minusMonths(1).toInstant());
```

If you don't need exactly a `Date` object, you can use the classes directly, provided by the package, even to get dates in other time-zones:

```
ZonedDateTime dateInUTC = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Auckland")).minusMonths(1);
```

Comment: I suggest changing this Answer to show a particular time zone, such as `ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )` rather than `ZoneOffset.UTC`. If someone really wanted UTC, then more appropriate to use `OffsetDateTime` than `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 11):

```
Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance()

// adding -1 month
calNow.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

// fetching updated time
Date dateBeforeAMonth = calNow.getTime();
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use `Calendar`

```
    java.util.Date da = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(da);
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    da = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: (I assume the use of `setTime` is for demonstration purposes as `Calendar.getInstance` will return a `Calendar` set to the current date/time...you also might like to put in `da = cal.getTime()` just so that you end up with a `Date` value at the end...)

Answer (score 7):

Using new java.time package in Java8 and Java9

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

LocalDate mydate = LocalDate.now(); // Or whatever you want
mydate = mydate.minusMonths(1);
```

The advantage to using this method is that you avoid all the issues about varying month lengths and have more flexibility in adjusting dates and ranges. The Local part also is Timezone smart so it's easy to convert between them.

As an aside, using java.time you can also get the day of the week, day of the month, all days up to the last of the month, all days up to a certain day of the week, etc.

```
mydate.plusMonths(1);
mydate.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)).getDayOfMonth();
mydate.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
```

Comment: Very good answer, thanks. There’s no need for the complications contained in many of the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Using [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) :

```
Date date = new DateTime().minusMonths(1).toDate();
```

JodaTime provides a convenient API for date manipulation.

Note that similar Date API will be introduced in JDK8 with the [JSR310](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen).

Comment: deprecated method.

Comment: The *Joda-Time* project is now in maintenance-mode. Its successor is built into Java 8 and late, the *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310. See modern solution in [Answer by Gregory Alan Bolcer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50339757/642706).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) from apache common. The library also supports adding Hour, Minute, etc.

```
Date date = DateUtils.addMonths(new Date(), -1)
```

Comment: Both of the troublesome `Date` classes are legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically, the `java.util.Date` class was replaced by [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html), and `java.sql.Date` by `LocalDate`. The Apache Commons library `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils` is no longer needed, its functionality now built into the *java.time* classes since Java 8.

Answer (score -1):

raduce 1 month of JDF

```
Date dateTo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(jdfMeTo.getJulianDate());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(dateTo);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        Date dateOf = cal.getTime();
        Log.i("dateOf", dateOf.getTime() + "");
        jdfMeOf.setJulianDate(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 
        cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH));
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.