# Java current date minus 3 months and start from month begining

Tags: java, date, date-manipulation

I need to get statistics for a quarter.

Example: today is February 10<sup>th</sup> 2018, I need to retrieve data from December 2017, from 1<sup>st</sup> to 31<sup>st</sup>, then from January 2018, from 1<sup>st</sup> to 30<sup>th</sup> and from February 1<sup>st</sup> to current date.

How can I achieve this using Java `Date`?

Comment: Don't use a `Date` for that ... at least use `Calendar` but you really should use a `LocalDate`. For the rest, google it. It can be found quickly. [java.util.Date - Deleting three months from a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311143/java-util-date-deleting-three-months-from-a-date) ... then set the day of month to 1 ... that's simple with a `LocalDate` too.

Comment: Please search before asking (and get a good answer faster). What you want, you can obtain it by combining the answers from [Get first date of current month in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241836/get-first-date-of-current-month-in-java) and [How to reduce one month from current date and stored in date variable using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392892/how-to-reduce-one-month-from-current-date-and-stored-in-date-variable-using-java/16392922). I too recommend the answers that use java.time, they are there under both the questions I link to.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth.now().minusMonths( 1 ).atEndOfMonth()  // or .atDay( 1 )
```

## Details

Get today’s date.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “Africa/Tunis” ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Get the [year-month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) of that date.

```
YearMonth ymCurrent = YearMonth.from( today ) ;
```

Add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to access the [`LocalDateRange`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class. This class represents as one object a pair of `LocalDate` objects, start date and stop date, for a date range from one date to the other date.

```
LocalDateRange rangeCurrent = LocalDateRange.ofClosed( ymCurrent.atDay( 1 ) , today ) ;
```

Move to previous month.

```
YearMonth ymPrevious = ymCurrent.minusMonths( 1 ) ;
LocalDateRange rangePrevious = LocalDateRange.ofClosed( ymPrevious.atDay( 1 ) , ymPrevious.atEndOfMonth() ) ;
```

Subtract yet another time for your third month.

Tip: Consider using the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a month starts with the first day of the month and runs up to, but does not include, the first day of the following month.

For another valid approach using *java.time* classes, see [the Answer by diston](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49257276/642706).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
// Get current date
Calendar start;
start = Calendar.getInstance();

// Go to beginning of month
start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
start.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
start.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
start.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

// Go 2 months back
my_date.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2);

// Get end of same month
Calendar end;
end = start.clone();
end.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
end.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
```

Then, do something similar for the other months

Comment: FYI, the troublesome `Calendar`  class has been legacy for years now, supplanted by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Java 8's java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) classes (or [threeten backport](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) for Java <= 7).

If you'll work only with day/month/year and don't care about hours and timezones, the best class to use is `LocalDate`. To create a specific date is easy:

```
// February 10th 2018
LocalDate current = LocalDate.of(2018, 2, 10);
```

Or you can call `LocalDate.now()` to get the current date.

Then, to get to December 1<sup>st</sup> 2017, you must subtract 2 months (2 months before February is December) and set the day to 1:

```
// start is December 1st 2017
LocalDate start = current
    // 2 months ago = December
    .minusMonths(2)
    // change day of month to 1st
    .withDayOfMonth(1);
```

Then you can loop from December 1<sup>st</sup> to February 10<sup>th</sup>:

```
LocalDate date = start;
while (date.isBefore(current)) {
    // do whatever you need with the date

    // go to the next day
    date = date.plusDays(1);
}
```

Note that `plusDays` returns a new object, so I must assign it to the same variable, otherwise it won't be changed.

I also used `isBefore`, which doesn't include the current date in the loop - it'll stop at February 9<sup>th</sup>. If you want to include February 10<sup>th</sup>, change the condition to `if (! date.isAfter(current))`

Comment: Tip: The `java.time.YearMonth` class makes this work simpler and makes the code more obvious as to our intentions. See my Answer for example usage.

Comment: @BasilBourque In this case, I think the codes are kinda equivalent, I don't see much difference between `current.minusMonths(2).withDayOfMonth(1)` and `YearMonth.from(current).minusMonths(2).atDay(1)` - just 2 different ways to do the same thing, IMO.

Comment: Why the downvote, please? I would consider it good style to leave a comment along with it?